# initializer is not a constant, error C2099, on compiling a module written in c for python

Tags: python, c, visual-c++, python-c-api

i tried to compile a python module called [distance](https://github.com/doukremt/distance/tree/master/cdistance), whith c "python setup.py install --with-c" using msvc 2017 on windows 10, i got this error ,

> Cdistance / distance.c (647): error C2099: initializer is not a
>   constant
>
> Cdistance / distance.c (689): error C2099: initializer is not a
>   constant
>
> Error: command 'C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \
>   2017 \ BuildTools \ VC \ Tools \ MSVC \ 14.10.25017 \ bin \ HostX64 \
>   x64 \ cl .exe 'failed with exit status 2

here is the code on line 647

```
   646 PyTypeObject IFastComp_Type = {
   647     PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
   648  "distance.ifast_comp", /* tp_name */
   649  sizeof(ItorState), /* tp_basicsize */
   650  0, /* tp_itemsize */
        (destructor)itor_dealloc, /* tp_dealloc */
        0, /* tp_print */
        0, /* tp_getattr */
        0, /* tp_setattr */
        0, /* tp_reserved */
        0, /* tp_repr */
        0, /* tp_as_number */
        0, /* tp_as_sequence */
        0, /* tp_as_mapping */
        0, /* tp_hash */
        0, /* tp_call */
        0, /* tp_str */
        0, /* tp_getattro */
        0, /* tp_setattro */
        0, /* tp_as_buffer */
        Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT, /* tp_flags */
        ifast_comp_doc, /* tp_doc */
        0, /* tp_traverse */
        0, /* tp_clear */
        0, /* tp_richcompare */
        0, /* tp_weaklistoffset */
        PyObject_SelfIter, /* tp_iter */
        (iternextfunc)ifastcomp_next, /* tp_iternext */
        0, /* tp_methods */
        0, /* tp_members */
        0, /* tp_getset */
        0, /* tp_base */
        0, /* tp_dict */
        0, /* tp_descr_get */
        0, /* tp_descr_set */
        0, /* tp_dictoffset */
        0, /* tp_init */
        PyType_GenericAlloc, /* tp_alloc */
        ifastcomp_new, /* tp_new */
    };
```

in the line 689 is another like strucure,

```
688  PyTypeObject ILevenshtein_Type = {
689     PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
        "distance.ilevenshtein", /* tp_name */
        sizeof(ItorState), /* tp_basicsize */
        0, /* tp_itemsize */
        (destructor)itor_dealloc, /* tp_dealloc */
        0, /* tp_print */
        0, /* tp_getattr */
        0, /* tp_setattr */
        0, /* tp_reserved */
        0, /* tp_repr */
```

both referenced as follow, in the same page

```
762 if (PyType_Ready(&IFastComp_Type) != 0 || PyType_Ready(&ILevenshtein_Type)!= 0)
763 #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
        return NULL;
    #else
        return;
    #endif

    Py_INCREF((PyObject *)&IFastComp_Type);
    Py_INCREF((PyObject *)&ILevenshtein_Type);
```

thanks

Comment: This line "*line 647*" is many lines. Which is 647 and which is 689?

Comment: Do you know how to initialize the global variables? One of those symbols is not a const. Discover which one and you are done. If you do not how - buy a good C book as we are not a free learning service

Comment: How and where is `ifast_comp_doc` declared? (I just compared it with a Python class we have written in C++. I cannot see something obviously wrong.)

Comment: i edited it as suggested by alk  , yes i do with a constant of course , but i didn't figured out which one ,

Comment: ifast_comp_doc is diclared in includes.h in line 74 [includes.h](https://github.com/doukremt/distance/blob/master/cdistance/includes.h)

Comment: @PeterJ: `const` does not create a constant in C.

Comment: here is The structure definition for PyTypeObject  [PyTypeObject  ](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have found the solution, by looking to the definition of the structure  PyTypeObject [PyTypeObject](https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/newtypes.html) , i have changed `yVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)` by `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)` and it compiles successfully, and i have tried some functions and it works, so the error is caused by `&PyType_Type` which is a `PyObject*`, i know that because `IFastComp_Type` is a globale varailble it should be initialised by a constante, but i still don't know why the author of the module gave `&PyType_Type` as argument ,  thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation for "defining new types"](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html).

```
PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
```

> This line is a bit of a wart; what we’d like to write is:
>
> `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)`
>
> as the type of a type object is “type”, but this isn’t strictly conforming C and some compilers complain. Fortunately, this member will be filled in for us by `PyType_Ready()`.

I presume that Visual C is the compiler that complains, and the module was written and tested with GCC...

Comment: I am not sure about the conformance, I think VC is not behaving correctly here

Comment: Fair enough - I was quoting the Python documentation rather than claiming to understand the C standard. It sounds like VC is wrong here, but the standard way of using the Python C interface is to write code that VC can cope with.

Comment: Had the same issue with MinGW's gcc on windows. writing `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)` helped.